# Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared galley image Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, zscaler

When trying to create a Virtual Machine from PS it's ending up with the error (this it of Zscaler log collector in Azure):
Cannot attach an existing OS disk if the VM is created from a platform, user or a shared galley image Azure

> #Test if the azure powershell modules are present on the system
> $scmd="Connect-AzAccount"
> $cmdout=Get-Command $scmd -eA SilentlyContinue -EV $serr -OV $sout
> if(!$cmdout.CommandType) {
> echo "Required powershell modules are missing. Please install the azure modules and retry"
> exit
> }
>
> #Sign in for this session
> Connect-AzAccount
>
> #Fetch the config file to be loaded
> if( $args[0] -ne $null ){
> $filename=$args[0]
> }
> else
> {
> $filename="./config.txt"
> }
>
> $SubSelect = 'n'
> Set-Item Env:\SuppressAzurePowerShellBreakingChangeWarnings "true"
> Do {
> $subs=Get-AzSubscription
>
> echo "Listing available subscriptions in your account"
> $subid=0
> $ProvisionSub=99999
> foreach ($sub in $subs) {
> echo "Subscription $subid :"
> echo $sub
> $subid++
> }
>
> if($subid -ge 1)
> {
> $ProvisionSub=Read-Host -Prompt "Select one of the above for provisioning"
> }
> else
> {
> $ProvisionSub=0
> }
>
> echo "Selected subscription for provisioning :"
> echo $subs[$ProvisionSub]
> $SubSelect=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter `"y`" to continue with this subscription or `"n`" to choose again"
> While($SubSelect -eq 'n' -or $SubSelect -eq 'N')
>
> if($SubSelect -ne 'y' -and $SubSelect -ne 'Y') {
> echo "You did not choose a subscription to deploy in, script will exit now"
> exit
> }
>
> $subscription=$subs[$ProvisionSub]
> echo "Script will continue to provision in the selected subscription $subscription "
> Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
> echo "Azure Subscription for current session set to the following"
> Get-AzContext
> $select=Read-Host -Prompt "Do you wish to continue(y/n):"
> if($select -ne 'y' -or $select -ne 'Y')
> {
> echo "Script terminating per user input"
> exit
> }
> echo "Provisioning will continue with the selected subscription"
>
> if ( -not (Test-Path $filename))
> {
> echo "Config file not found at $filename"
> exit
> }
> else
> {
> echo "Found the configuration file, populating deployment variables from $filename"
> }
>
> #Sanity run, set this to n when running actual creation
> $sanityrun='n'
>
> #Initialize config entries from the configuration file provided
> $name=''
> $rgname=''
> $niccount=1
> $rgcreate="n"
> $storename=''
> $mgmtsubnetname=''
> $svcsubnetname=''
> $vnetname=''
> $vnetprefix=''
> $mgmtsnetprefix=''
> $svcsubnetprefix=''
> $vmsize=''
> $location=''
> $osimage=''
> $dstStorageURI=''
> $datadisk="Copy"
> $datadisksize=0
> $datadisksrcURI=''
> $osdisksrcURI=''
> $dataimageURI=''
> $dstContainer=''
> $vnetrgname=''
> $avsetname=''
> $avcheck="No"
>
> #Parse the config file provided and load the values
>
> foreach ($line in Get-Content $filename) {
> if($line -match "^#.*") {
> #Commented
> continue
> }
> if( [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($line)) {
> #Empty line
> continue
> }
> $entries=$line.split("=",2,[StringSplitOptions]'RemoveEmptyEntries')
> #$entries=$line.split("=")
> $e1=$entries[0]
> $e2=$entries[1]
> Write-Host $e1 $e2 -Separator ","
> $key=$e1.Trim()
> $value=$e2.Trim()
> #echo "Got entries" $entries[0] "->" $entries[1]
> if($key -eq "name") {
> $name=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "avset") {
> $avsetname=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "rgname") {
> $rgname=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "vnetrg") {
> $vnetrgname=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "createrg") {
> $rgcreate=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "storename") {
> $storename=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "createstorage") {
> $storecreate=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "mgmtsubnetname") {
> $mgmtsubnetname=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "svcsubnetname") {
> $svcsubnetname=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "vnetname") {
> $vnetname=$value
> continue
>
> if($key -eq "niccount") {
> $niccount=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "vnetprefix") {
> $vnetprefix=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "mgmtsubnetprefix") {
> $mgmtsnetprefix=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "svcsubnetprefix") {
> $svcsubnetprefix=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "vmsize") {
> $vmsize=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "location") {
> $location=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "dstStorageURI") {
> $dstStorageURI=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "srcOsURI") {
> $osimage=$value
> continue
>
> if($key -eq "osuri") {
> $osdisksrcURI=$value
> continue
>
> if($key -eq "sastok") {
> $sastok=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "attach") {
> $attachdisk=$value
> continue
> }
> if($key -eq "dstContainer") {
> $dstContainer=$value
> continue
> }
>
> }
>
> echo "Name=$name Rgname=$rgname Location=$location"
> if($vnetrgname -eq '')
> {
> $vnetrgname=$rgname
> }
>
> $loclist=Get-AzLocation
> $loccheck=0
>
> foreach($loc in $loclist.Location){
> if($loc -like $location){
> $loccheck=1
> }
> }
>
> if($loccheck -eq 1){
> Write-Host "The virtual instance will be deployed in $location"
> else {
>
> Write-Error -Message "The location provided in configuration file :- $location is not a valid input. Please correct the same and rerun the script"
> exit
> }
>
> #Fetch resource group and storage account configured in the conf file
> $rg=Get-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ev notPresent -ea 0
> $rgcreatechoice='n'
> $storecreatechoice='n'
>
> #If resource group does not exist, provision it before proceeding
> if($rg.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded") {
> echo "The resource group $rgname does not exist, do you wish to create it in $location(y/n):"
> $rgcreatechoice=Read-Host
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y') {
> echo "Creating resourcegroup $rgname in $location"
> $rg=New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgname -Location $location
> if($rg.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded") {
> echo "Error creating resource group. Script will exit now"
> exit
> }
> echo "Created resource group. Continuing to provision the storage account"
> $storecreatechoice='y'
> }else
> {
> echo "Resource group specified does not exist in the selected subscription. Exiting"
> exit
> }
> }
>
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'n')
> {
> $store=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $storename -ev stnotPresent -ea 0
> if($store.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded"){
> echo "The Storage account provided `"$storename`" doesn't exist in $rgname"
> echo "Do you wish to provision the storage account now(y/n):"
> $storecreatechoice=Read-Host
> if($storecreatechoice -ne 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -ne 'Y'){
> echo "VM creation cannot continue without storage account. Exiting."
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location while script executed"
> echo "Please delete it if no longer in use"
> }
> exit
> }
> }
> }
> $storetype='Standard_LRS'
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Preparing to provision storage account $storename in resource group $rgname"
> echo "Do you need geo redundant store or locally reduntant store"
> echo "Enter 1 for geo reduntant(Standard_GRS) or 2 for locally reduntant(Standard_LRS), if you need"
> echo "other options, enter `"n`" to exit now and provision the storage account manually "
> echo "Enter your choice: "
> $storetypechoice=Read-Host
> if($storetypechoice -eq 1)
> {
> echo "Store type set to Standard_GRS"
> $storetype="Standard_GRS"
> }
> if($storetypechoice -eq 2)
> {
> echo "Store type set to Standard_LRS"
> $storetype="Standard_LRS"
> }
> if($storetypechoice -eq 'n' -or $storetypechoice -eq 'N')
> {
> echo "Exiting deployment as per user input"
> exit
> }
> echo "Creating storage account. This is a long operation. Please wait till it completes."
> $store=New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $storename -Location $location -SkuName $storetype
>
> }
>
> if($store.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded")
> {
> echo "Storage account creation did not complete successfully. Exiting deployment"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location. Please delete it manually if not needed"
> }
> exit
> }else
> {
> #Check if the container exists in target account
> $containercheck=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $dstContainer -Context $store.Context -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
> if($containercheck.Name -ne $dstContainer)
> {
> #Create Storage container with the provided name
> echo "Storage account creation successful, creating container for disk storage."
> New-AzStorageContainer -Name $dstContainer -Permission Off -Context $store.Context
> }
>
> }
> #Availability set check
> if($avsetname -ne '') {
> $avset=Get-AzAvailabilitySet -Name $avsetname -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
> if($avset.Name -eq $avsetname) {
> if($avset.Managed) {
> echo "This availability set is not supported by the vm type being deployed,"
> echo "Please use a classic availability set to deploy this VM"
> exit
> }
> echo "Availability set present, vm instance will be provisioned within availability set"
> $avcheck="Yes"
> sleep 10
> }
> }
>
> if($avcheck -eq "No" -and $avsetname -ne '') {
> echo "Creating availability set for the VM"
> $avset=New-AzAvailabilitySet -Name $avsetname -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -Sku classic
> sleep 10
> if($avset.Name -eq $avsetname) {
> echo "Created availability set, deployment in progress"
> sleep 5
> }else
> {
> echo "Deployment will stop now, failed to create availability set"
> echo "To deploy, create a classic availability set in the required resource group"
> echo "And execute the script again"
> exit
> }
> $avcheck="Yes"
> }
>
> #Network configuration for the virtual machine
>
> #create the interface names
> $nicnames=@()
> if($niccount -gt 0) {
> echo "Creating $niccount nic names"
> for($i=0; $i -lt $niccount; $i++) {
> $nicname=$name+"*nic*"+$i
> $nicnames+=$nicname
>
> }
> }else {
> echo "The vm needs at least 1 interface to be configured, current value is $niccount"
> echo "Script will exit now. Please correct the config file as per recommendations and try again"
> exit
> }
>
> $ipnames=@()
> if($niccount -gt 0) {
> echo "Creating $niccount ip names"
> for($i=0; $i -lt $niccount; $i++) {
> $ipname=$name+"*ip*"+$i
> $ipnames+=$ipname
>
> }
> }
> if($vnetrgname -ne $rgname){
> #Validate the resource group for provisioning vnet exists
> }
>
> $vnet=Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $vnetrgname -ev vnetError -ea 0
> $vnetcreate='n'
> if($vnet.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded")
> {
> echo "VirtualNetwork $vnetname exists, checking for subnet"
> $mgmtsnet=Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $mgmtsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev snetPresent -ea 0
> $svcsnet=Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $svcsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev snetPresent -ea 0
> }else
> {
> echo "Do you wish to create the Virtual Network as per the configuration provided"
> $vnetcreate=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter y/n"
> if($vnetcreate -ne 'y' -and $vnetcreate -ne 'Y')
> {
>
> echo "Virtual Network configuration for the VM instance is not provisioned"
> echo "This script will now exit"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
> echo "New Virtual network $vnetname with prefix $vnetprefix will be created in $location"
> $vnetcreate=Read-Host -Prompt "Do you wish to continue (y/n)"
> if($vnetcreate -ne 'y' -and $vnetcreate -ne 'Y')
> {
> echo "Script will exit now as per user input"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
> $mgmtsnet=New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $mgmtsubnetname -AddressPrefix $mgmtsnetprefix -ev sNetCreate -ea 0
> if($mgmtsnetprefix -ne $svcsubnetprefix) {
> $svcsnet=New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $svcsubnetname -AddressPrefix $svcsnetprefix -ev sNetCreate -ea 0
> $vnet=New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $vnetrgname -Location $location -AddressPrefix $vnetprefix -Subnet $mgmtsnet,$svcsnet -ev vNetCreate -ea 0
> }
> else
> {
> $vnet=New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetname -ResourceGroupName $vnetrgname -Location $location -AddressPrefix $vnetprefix -Subnet $mgmtsnet -ev vNetCreate -ea 0
> $svcsnet=$mgmtsnet
> }
>
> }
>
> if($vnet.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded"){
> echo "Virtual network creation failed or script was unable to fetch"
> echo "the Virtual network configuration. Please check the configuration"
> echo "for possible errors and execute the script further"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
> $snetcreate='n'
> $mgmtsnet=Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $mgmtsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev sNetPresent -ea 0
>
> if($mgmtsnet.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded") {
>
> echo "A subnet $mgmtsubnetname with the required configuration $mgmtsnetprefix"
> echo "Was not found in $vnetname "
> echo "The instance provisioning will exit if subnet is not created"
> $snetcreate=Read-Host -Prompt "Do you wish to create it now (y/n)"
> if($snetcreate -ne 'y' -and $snetcreate -ne 'Y') {
> echo "You have chosen not to provision the subnet"
> echo "The script will exit now"
> echo "Please make sure all prerequisites are met and "
> echo "execute the script to provision the instance"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
> $mgmtsnet=New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetname -AddressPrefix $snetprefix -ev sNetCreate -ea 0
> Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $mgmtsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev sNetAssign -ea 0
> }
>
> $svcsnet=Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $svcsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev sNetPresent -ea 0
> if($svcsnet.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded") {
>
> echo "A subnet $svcsubnetname with the required configuration $svcsnetprefix"
> echo "Was not found in $vnetname "
> echo "The instance provisioning will exit if subnet is not created"
> $snetcreate='n'
> $snetcreate=Read-Host -Prompt "Do you wish to create it now (y/n)"
> if($snetcreate -ne 'y' -and $snetcreate -ne 'Y') {
> echo "You have chosen not to provision the subnet"
> echo "The script will exit now"
> echo "Please make sure all prerequisites are met and "
> echo "execute the script to provision the instance"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
> $svcsnet=New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $svcsubnetname -AddressPrefix $svcsnetprefix -ev sNetCreate -ea 0
> Set-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $svcsubnetname -VirtualNetwork $vnet -ev sNetAssign -ea 0
> }
>
> if(($mgmtsnet.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded") -or ($svcsnet.ProvisioningState -ne "Succeeded")){
> echo "Subnet provisioning failed"
> echo "Deployment cannot continue"
> if($rgcreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $rgcreatechoice -eq 'Y' ){
> echo "Resource group $rgname was provisioned in $location "
> echo "It can be removed if not in use"
> }
> if($storecreatechoice -eq 'y' -or $storecreatechoice -eq 'Y'){
> echo "Storage account $storename was provisoned by this script"
> echo "It can be removed if not used"
> }
> exit
> }
>
> if($sanityrun -eq 'y'){
> Write-Host "Exiting sanity check" -Foreground Green
> exit
> }
>
> #Start creation of the VM object
> echo "Creating the vm object...."
> #$cred=Get-Credential
> if($avcheck -eq "Yes") {
> $vm = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $name -VMSize $vmsize -AvailabilitySetId $avset.Id
> }else
> {
> $vm = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $name -VMSize $vmsize
> }
> #$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Linux -ComputerName $name -Credential $cred
>
> #Create interfaces and ip objects as per config file
> $nics=@()
> $pip=@()
> $pipopt='n'
> echo "Do you wish to allocate public ip address to the instance"
> $pipopt=Read-Host -Prompt "Enter y or n to proceed"
> echo "Generating interface configuration and attaching ip addresses...."
> if($pipopt -eq 'y' -or $pipopt -eq 'Y'){
> for($i=0; $i -lt $niccount ; $i++) {
> $pip=New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $ipnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
> #$nic=New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -SubnetId $svcsnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id
> if($i -eq 0) {
> $nic=New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nicnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -SubnetId $mgmtsnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id
> $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id -Primary
> }else
> {
> $nic=New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nicnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -SubnetId $svcsnet.Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id
> }
> $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
> echo "Nics = $nics"
> }
> }
> else {
> for($i=0; $i -lt $niccount ; $i++) {
>
> if($i -eq 0) {
> $nic=New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nicnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -SubnetId $mgmtsnet.Id
> $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id -Primary
> }
> else
> {
> $nic=New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nicnames[$i] -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -SubnetId $svcsnet.Id
> }
> $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
> echo "Nics = $nics"
> }
> }
>
> #Setting up disks for the VM
> clear
> echo "Setting up the disks."
> $osdiskname=$name+"_"+"osdisk.vhd"
> $blob="$dstStorageURI/$dstContainer"
> $osDiskUri = "$blob/$osdiskname"
> $osimageUri = "$osimage"
>
> echo "Disk info for the VM "
> echo "OS Disk : $osdiskname"
> echo "Blob : $blob"
> echo "OS disk URI : $osDiskUri"
>
> sleep 10
> clear
> echo "Copying disks to the path"
>
> $storecontext=$store.Context
> Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $osimageUri -Context $storecontext -DestContainer $dstContainer -DestBlob $osdiskname
> $osstatus=Get-AzStorageBlobCopyState -Context $storecontext -Blob $osdiskname -Container $dstContainer
> While($osstatus.Status -ne "Success") {
> sleep 20
> $osstatus=Get-AzStorageBlobCopyState -Context $storecontext -Blob $osdiskname -Container $dstContainer
> if($osstatus.Status -ne "Pending") {
> Break
> }
> }
>
> $vm=Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osdiskname -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption Attach -Linux
> #Create the azure Virtual machine
> clear
> echo "Disk setup completed, vm object generated succesfully. Creating the instance."
> New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $location -VM $vm -Verbose

I replaced the line:

$vm=Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osdiskname -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption Attach -Linux

with

```
$vm=Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osdiskname -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption FromImage -Linux
```

Comment: This is not a shared disk but a VHD file stored in storage account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have virtual machine with shared gallery image vm in azure like below:

[image]

[image]

Now you should create a managed disk from disk, VHD or snapshot following this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/create-vm-from-managed-os-disks) disk should not attached to any other vm like [this](https://i.imgur.com/8bC9gpP.png)

When I ran the below PowerShell script, I am able to attach the existing os disk from the shared gallery image vm to new vm.

```c
# Set variables
$resourceGroupName = 'YourResourceGroup'
$osDiskName = 'YourManagedDisk'
$location = 'eastUS'
$destinationResourceGroup = 'YourDestinationRG'
$subnetName = 'YourSubnet'
$vnetName = 'YourVNet'
$nsgName = 'YourNsg'
$ipName = 'YourIP'
$nicName = 'YourNicName'
$vmName = 'YourVMName'

# Get the existing OS disk
$osDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $osDiskName

# Create subnet configuration
$singleSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24

# Create virtual network
$vnet = New-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $singleSubnet

# Create NSG and deny RDP traffic
$rdpRule = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name myRdpRule -Description "Deny RDP" `
    -Access Deny -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 110 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389

$nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -Name $nsgName -SecurityRules $rdpRule

# Create public IP
$pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name $ipName -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -AllocationMethod static

# Create NIC
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Set VM name and size (using an allowed SKU)
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize "Standard_B8ms"

# Add NIC to VM configuration
$vmConfig = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id

# Set OS disk configuration
$vmConfig = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vmConfig -ManagedDiskId $osDisk.Id -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption Attach -Windows

# Create the VM
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $destinationResourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

Output:

```c
RequestId IsSuccessStatusCode StatusCode ReasonPhrase
--------- ------------------- ---------- ------------
                         True         OK
```

[image]